# Issues using msbuild.exe Microsoft Build tools 2013

Tags: c++, msbuild

On a fresh Win7 x64 machine I installed the **.Net4.5.1** and then **[Microsoft Build tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40760)**
I have a VS2013 C++ project with complete sources and files. When I try to compile the VS2103 project with the msbuild.exe it is failing with error below

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. 
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists 
on disk.
```

**What else do I need to install on the Win7 x64 machine to get it working ?**

Comment: You need to post your .proj or .sln text.  This usually happens because a variable is emtpy.  Consider this "c:\$(MyVariableUndefined)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props".....If MyVariableUndefined is not defined, it screws up things.